# Foreach loop within a foreach loop based on different models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foreach

I am using asp mvc5 to create a slider based on the **[camera jquery plugin](http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/)** .

I have a `foreach` loop which brings data into the slider

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div data-src="../img/front-slides/1.jpg">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <h1 class="animated bounceInRight delay1">
                        @item.Name
                    </h1>
                    <p class="animated bounceInUp delay2">@item.FrontPageBlurb</p>
                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-info animated bounceInUp delay3" href="@Url.Action("Details", "Product", new { id = @item.ProductId })">View Details</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Product", new { item.ProductId })" class="img-responsive lead animated bounceInUp delay1 pull-right" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And the controller looks like this

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string[] bgImgUri = {"../img/front-slides/4.jpg" , "../img/front-slides/4.jpg" , "../img/front-slides/4.jpg" };

        ViewBag.bgImgUri = bgImgUri;

        var products = db.Products.Include(p => p.Brand).Include(p => p.Category).Where(_ => _.ActiveProduct == true && _.ImageData != null && _.FrontPage != null && _.FrontPageBlurb != null).Take(4);

        return View(products);
    }
```

Currently the background image for the slider is one image.

```
 <div data-src="../img/front-slides/1.jpg">
```

However i would like to list through a few of them based on the `@ViewBag.bgImgUri`

I am getting about as lost as the plot for inception in creating a `foreach` inside a `foreach` to create and am not even sure it is what i need to create this .

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @foreach (var bg in Viewbag.bgImgUri){
         <div data-src="@bg">
    }
 ...
```

Would it be easier to put this in a ViewModel? And if so , how would i go about doing this. I have only create very rudimentary ViewModels so far and am still trying to wrap my head around the concept.

Thanks

Comment: Avoid to use such this codes. Because of program complexity of O(nm)!!

Comment: The "amount of time" needed to render/analyze _n_ products, each with _m_ background images.

Comment: That is Algorithmic speed analysis of program execution/run. @AndreiV is right. This complex codes affect more in web applications.

Comment: If these values (_n_ & _m_) are relatively small, you shouldn't have a problem with using this approach. However, since these images repeat themselves _for each product_ you would probably want to try to generate a separate container for the images in your `Viewbag.bgImgUri` (render each image only one time) and selectively make them visible.